# casting a type parameter to a basic type without boxing

Tags: c#, generics, optimization, casting, boxing

Is there any way to make a code like this work:

```
public class Func2<A, B>
{
    private Func<A, B> f;

    public Func2(Func<A, B> f)
    {
        this.f = f;
    }

    public object invoke(object obj, long l)
    {
        if (typeof(B) == typeof(long))
        {
            if (obj != null)
                l = (long)obj;
            return f((B)l); //error! cannot convert type 'long' to 'B'
        } else {
            return f((B)obj);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I cannot directly cast B to long without casting B to object first. I am trying to avoid at all costs having to box, as it would slow down a lot fast operations on functions. So is there any way to achieve this?

I know I could actually define a specialized Func2 to specifically handle the case of when B is a long. But as the arity of the function grows, the combination of longs and objects grow  exponentially - and in the real use case I want also to support doubles !. Is there any way to support this without boxing? Maybe with unsafe code?

Thank you!
Cauê

Comment: what are you trying to do here? if you let us know there might be  better approach

Comment: I'm writing an haXe (haxe.org) target for C#, and I am trying to find the best way to represent HaXe's function types in C#. HaXe function types, differently from the CLR, allows a Func<long, object> to be cast to a Func<object, object> (for example). So I am trying to find a way to be able to call unboxed params when we can, and call the boxed version when we aren't aware of the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overload the method, and instead of casting the `long` value to `A`, you can cast the delegate to `Func<long, B>`:

```
public class Func2<A, B> {

  private Func<A, B> f;

  public Func2(Func<A, B> f) {
    this.f = f;
  }

  public B invoke(long a) {
    if (typeof(A) == typeof(long)) {
      return (f as Func<long, B>)(a);
    } else {
      throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
  }

  public B invoke(object a) {
    return f((A)a);
  }

}
```

Example:

```
Func2<long, string> f = new Func2<long, string>(l => l.ToString());

Console.WriteLine(f.invoke(42)); // calls the invoke(long) method
Console.WriteLine(f.invoke("x")); // calls the invoke(object) method
```

Comment: Thank you !!! I won't overload the method, because this would mean that I'd have to overload ALL possible combinations of types (for 2 types, it's easy, but think of when you have a function of arity 5 or 6 ! ) But thanks, that really solved up the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the answer ! : )

```
public object invoke(object obj, long l)
{
    if (typeof(B) == typeof(long))
    {
        if (obj != null)
            l = (long)obj;
        Func<A, long> x = (Func<A, long>)(object)f;
        return x(l);
    } else {
        return f((B)obj);
    }
}
```

This way we don't have to autobox the long to object, but we actually cast the Func type to receive the long we specified!

As for why I am trying to do this, read the above comment, and I'd still be trying to find a best way to do this.

By now, we have the following Haxe code:

```
var f:Int->Int->Float = function(x:Int, y:Int) return x + y + 0.5;
var f2:Dynamic->Dynamic->Dynamic = f; // ok
var f3:Dynamic->Int->Dynamic = f; //also ok
f2(10, 30); // ok - this will box the 10 and 30
```

What I'm trying to do is create a Fun3 type that has an invoke call that will take both the boxed and unboxed arguments. If the underlying function really accepts unboxed types, it will try first to use them.